# Authentication in Microservices with spring

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I wanna refactor a monolithic spring boot application basically a web app with login and functionalities for customers. We already have a Security implementation which works with a session id stored as a cookie but I dont have much knowledge about it at all and im completetly new to this topic. It seems JWT is a better solution for Microservices because of an independent authentication service.

So my questions are:

- is it alot of work to create a JWT authentication service and exchange the session id implemenation? (since im doing it for my bachelor thesis and have a clear deadline)
- can I stay at the session ids while using microservices?
- are there maybe other ways to implement authentication?

Answer (score 0):

> is it alot of work to create a JWT authentication service and exchange
>   the session id implemenation? (since im doing it for my bachelor
>   thesis and have a clear deadline)

This question is hard to answer, as it depends how tightly coupled your particular implementation is.  It's certainly not trivial.

> can I stay at the session ids while using microservices?

Yes, but you need to figure out how to federate sessions across the microservices (i.e. how to get the information in the session from one service to the other).  Overall, this represents a risk of tight coupling between services, so I'd recommend treating this as a transitionary step only.

> are there maybe other ways to implement authentication?

As many as the day is long.  That being said, without specific reason to do otherwise, I generally prefer to stick to the middle of the road.

Answer (score 0):

Typical user sessions is not recommended in microservices.You should use Stateless architecture and tokens (Tokens stored in database or JWT).

It's better to use [Spring Boot OAuth2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

You should implement an Authorization server and Resource servers with Spring Boot.

**Authorization server:**

1. Choose the token storage method (JWT,Jdbc,...)
2. Configure client details
3. Add a RESTful Api for user info or enable /oauth/check_token api.(Called by Resource servers)

**Resource servers:**

1. Set user-info-uri or token-info-uri in Spring boot OAuth2 properties.
2. Extends `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` class for securing url mappings.

Comment: the whole monolith runs with user sessions at the moment. My mission is to extract one service prototypiclally and run it indenpendently with own database etc. Is it alot of work to change the whole authorization/authentification stuff as a complete newbie?

Comment: I can help you to change the authorization mechanism.
First.you should read Spring Boot OAuth2 reference.

Comment: If you want to use typical sessions,you should use session replication.https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html